# Laravel Hashing with Sentry or Sentinel

Tags: laravel, sentinel

I'm using Laravel and Sentry (Sentinel), i'm new for laravel.

when i try to develop laravel with Sentry, there's something that stops me from doing so, it's hash

```
http://localhost:8000/users/4wnpje
```

and my question is, is hash is created just for user profile?

how I can make that hash to my product page? because my product page still show plain text

```
http://localhost:8000/products/12
```

could someone explain it to me please?

Comment: What do you mean with "A hash" ? What's that URL has to do with a hash? What does it has to do with Sentinel?

Comment: http://localhost:8000/users/4wnpje the user id is protected, i want my product page protected too